# Make button send email, redirect page, and trigger a url-based download

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have an email form at www.ezrite.com/email_form.php

Using this click function in my page to capture an email and trigger download for user of a zip file:

```
$('#toinfo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location="http://www.ezrite.com/d/infopage.html";
    },   1000);
```

However, the email is never sent and I'm wondering if the anchor tag is hijacking the button and preventing the email from posting??

GOAL: To trigger a download of a zip file, send email input to an email, and to redirect the page when the button is clicked..

IDEA: I'm thinking of using a second setTimeout at this point

Comment: maybe check out [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and skip the page reload altogether

Answer (score 0):

On the click of the button, you can initiate the ajax command. Once the data is POSTED to the url, it will call a done function. In your case to redirect the user to the next page.

```
$('#toinfo').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "email_form.php?do=send",
      data: { femail: "'+$(['name=femail']).value()+'"}          
    }).done(function() {
      window.location="http://www.ezrite.com/d/infopage.html";
    }).fail(function(){
      alert("Could not send data.");
    });
});
```

Comment: <a href="http://www.ezrite.com/music/Powaqqatsi.zip" onclick="return false;">
<button id="toinfo" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">DOWNLOAD ALBUM</button></a> I need the downloading of the zip to also be triggered onclick of the button, along with email post and redirect of current page.